# Use Strtotime to format variables for hour, minute, and AM/PM

Tags: php, strtotime

I am trying to figure out how to use strtotime with the values below. I think this should be simple but I just can't get it. I would like the output to be something like:

date("H:i:s") - which looks like - 16:30:00

```
<?php

$hour = "4";
$minute = "30";
$period = "PM";

echo strtotime("$hour $minute $period")

?>
```

I've been digging around for a while but can't figure this out. Any ideas would be very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell/show us what you expect to be echoed? Are you wanting to echo the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC?

Comment: hi! hoping to output it like "16:30:00"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To echo 16:30:00 from 4, 30 and PM

```
echo date("H:i:s", strtotime("$hour:$minute $period"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to indicate the separator between minutes and hours:

```
echo strtotime("$hour:$minute $period");
```

should work. (In fact I tested and did work).

**Edit**
So if you need the output to be like `HH:MM:SS`, then you have to print extra info:

```
echo date("H:i:s", strtotime("$hour:$minute $period"));
```

Comment: Thanks! How would i output this like (16:30:00)

Comment: Well strtotime will give you an `UNIX timestamp`, not a 16:30:00 format

Answer (score 2):

you could do it like this-

```
$hour = date("h"); 
$minute = date("i"); 
$period = date("A"); 


echo $hour . ":" . $minute . " " . $period;
```

it will output 07:30 AM

you could add another variable for seconds also-

```
$hour = date("h"); 
$minute = date("i");
$seconds = date("s"); 
$period = date("A"); 


echo $hour . ":" . $minute . ":" . $seconds . " " . $period;
```

this will output 07:30:00 AM